# Erro de mensagem alert

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Gostaria de saber como posso concertar o seguinte problema que estou tendo com a resposta do `alert`. Eu faço o `INSERT` de itens para `MySQL`, até ai tudo bem. Contudo, se algum arquivo der falha e outros conseguirem ser enviados no *loop* o aviso `alert` da mensagem de erro.

Gostaria de saber como posso alterar o código abaixo para funcionar da seguinte forma:

Contar o valor total de dados enviados com sucesso e dados que ocorreram falha no envio, desta forma podendo ficar com um só `alert`, exemplo:

Total de envios com **Acerto X** com **Falha X**.

```
<?php
for($i=1; $i<=$total; $i++) {
    // Insere os dados no banco de dados
    $sql = $MySQLiconn->query("INSERT INTO `medias` SET `cat`='".$subcat["cat"]."', `subcat`='".$subcat["id"]."'");
}

if($sql) { ?><script>
    alert('<?php echo $total." Itens inseridos com sucesso !!!"; ?>');
    window.location.href='index.php';
    </script><? }
else {
    ?>
    <script>
    alert('error Erro ao tentar inserir os itens tente nova mente');
    </script>
    <?
}
?>
```

Comment: comece conSertando a gramática...

Comment: Não percebi nada...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que contar o resultados da query dentro do loop:

```
<?php
    $total_sucesso = 0;
    $total_erros = 0;

    for($i=1; $i<=$total; $i++) {
        // Insere os dados no banco de dados
        if ($MySQLiconn->query("INSERT INTO `medias` SET `cat`='".$subcat["cat"]."', `subcat`='".$subcat["id"]."'")) {
            $total_sucesso++;
        }
        else {
            $total_erros++;
        }
    }

    ?><script>
        alert('Total de envios com sucesso <?=$total_sucesso; ?> e erros <?=$total_erros;?>.');
        window.location.href='index.php';
        </script>
    <?
?>
```

Dá até pra você exibir uma lista com os itens que deram erro:

```
    if ($MySQLiconn->query("INSERT INTO `medias` SET `cat`='".$subcat["cat"]."', `subcat`='".$subcat["id"]."'")) {
        $total_sucesso++;
    }
    else {
        $total_erros.= $subcat["cat"] . "\n";
    }
```

E então, na mensagem:

```
alert('<?=$total_sucesso; ?> envios com sucesso. Erros: <?=$total_erros;?>.');
```

Comment: Isso eu havia feito o método que eu estou usando atualmente cria uma listagem de dados enviados com acerto e falha com tudo imagina como ficaria a lista se eu enviar 100 itens de uma só vez por isso optei em usar o alert pois fica um aviso único.

Answer (score 1):

```
query("INSERT INTO `medias` SET `cat`='".$subcat["cat"]."', `subcat`='".$subcat["id"]."'");
  if ($sql) {
  $total_envios++;
  } else {
  $total_erros++;
  }
}

if ($sql) {
    echo "
        alert('".$total_envios." Itens inseridos com sucesso !!!\n
        ".$total_erros." Itens com falhas no cadastro !!!"."');
        window.location.href='index.php';
        ";
 } else {         
    echo "
        alert('error Erro ao tentar inserir os itens tente nova mente');
        ";
 }

?>
```

Comment: Ola Marcio, bem vindo ao SOPT. Obrigado por responder mas considere acrescentar uma pequena explicação sobre o que alterou e porque alterou.

Answer (score 1):

Misturar tags abertura do PHP dentro de string JavaScript não é uma boa ideia, porque dificulta a leitura do código.

Sugiro simplificar da seguinte maneira:

```
<?php
// salvar os dados em variáveis
$mensagem = 'error Erro ao tentar inserir os itens tente novamente';
$location = false;
if ($sql) {
    $mensagem =  $total . ' Itens inseridos com sucesso';
    $location = 'index.php';
}

// criar e exibir o javascript
echo '<script>';
printf("alert('%s');\n", $mensagem); // <- atenção para as aspas simples
if (!empty($location)) {
    printf("window.location.href = '%s'\n", $location);
}
echo '</script>';
```

utilizei a função `printf()` em algumas linhas para exibir as *strings* formatadas. O simbolo `%s` será substituído pelo parâmetro seguinte. [Veja a documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.printf.php) para mais detalhes.

Answer (score 1):

A maneira mais correta de fazer esse tipo ação, é usar Ajax.

1. PHP não se relaciona com JavaScript e Vice&Versa (ñ faça gambi pfpfpf)
2. Quando precisamos desse tipo de relacionamento (pergunta - resposta) utiliza-se a função Ajax

Vamos ao problema:

Foi executada uma Query no Back-End e após foi informado o resultado.
Como o javascript não consegue enxergar essa resposta, até o momento não temos uma solução.

Para chegar em uma solução, será necessário fazer o uso de Ajax, que vai disparar um requisição ao seu arquivo, e nessa requisição, você dirá que precisa de uma reposta, usando semântica HTTP que no caso será GET.

A resposta virá no corpo de sua requisição, e no javascript você então receberá essa reposta, e poderá avaliar o resultado. Assim poderá lançar uma mensagem ao usuário.

Exemplo prático usando a JQuery

```
$.get('/pagina_do_meu_site&ajax="verifica"').success(function(response){
    if(response>0){
      alert('Itens inseridos com sucesso');
    }else{
      alert('Houve falha na inserção de dados');
    }
});
```

No back-end PHP (vou utilizar o modo mais simples)

```
<?php
  if($_GET['ajax']=='verifica'){
      echo '1';  //aqui o php retornará o valor 1 para o javascript
      exit;
  }
?>
```

Comment: Sem [Not Enough jQuery](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48195/223068), por favor. Usar ajax é Overkill pra uma coisa tão simples! O Javascript está sendo usado APENAS para exibir uma mensagem, nada mais! Você quer usar ajax para isso? Da forma que está sendo feita atende perfeita o que o OP quer. Imagina se o usuário faz 10 inserts na base, são 10 alerts pipocando na tela dele... ridículo.

Comment: Jovem, utilizar a maneira mais fácil nem sempre é a correta. É por isso que programadores PHP são mal vistos dentro das empresas, por tomar esse tipo de atitude.

Comment: Eu não disse *mais fácil*, disse mais coerente. Você não sabe como as informações estão sendo enviadas, como é o form nem nada, e já vem sugerindo isso tudo ? Mudança total de estrutura ?

Comment: Só php permite cara, por isso é tao mal vista, isso não existe, comunicar diretamente back-end com front-end.

Comment: Eu sei, mas isso é um contexto mais amplo. Você não sabe como está a estrutura do usuário, nem se ele separa as camadas. Enfim...

Comment: Nem por isso minha resposta está errada. Há um diferença de você pegar um usuário que segue padrão e outro que não segue. Nem por isso eu menosprezo tais repostas. A minha resposta foi mostrar a diferença entre padrões de projeto, se você me negativou, tudo bem, é o seu direto. Há dois mundos paralelos jovem, estou mostrando um dos lados.

Comment: Exatamente, não disse que a resposta está errada ou é ruim, só não é pertinente à pergunta. Você pode sugerir como um comentário a mudança de estrutura, mas não como resposta, na minha opinião. E ainda com tecnologias(ajax e jquery) que nem foram relacionadas na pergunta. No SO gringo você teria recebido uns 10 votos negativos.

Comment: ^^ Ta serto (y)

Comment: Grato pela ajuda de todos.